# Currency conversion api web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a new to MVC and still learning! I am trying to create a very basic App in my web which allows users to convert money value according to their preference. I made the web APi and was successful to call the service to my forms. However, in my controller I managed to get the currencies (names) to the index view, but cannot post the form back  once entering a value in the text box to generate the partial view! What am I doing wrong in my codes?!

Currency Controller

```
namespace MVC_ATM.Controllers
{
    public class CurrencyController : Controller
    {
      [HttpGet]
        // GET: Currency
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CurrenciesClient Cur = new CurrenciesClient();
           var listCurrency = Cur.findAll();
           SelectList list = new SelectList(listCurrency,"Id", "CurrencyName");
           ViewBag.listCurrencies = list;
            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Currencies cur)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string errors = string.Join("<br />", ModelState.Values
                                        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                return new ContentResult { Content = errors };


                var rate = Convert.ToDecimal(cur.ConversionRate);

                if (cur.CurrencyName == cur.CurrencyName)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CurrencyCountry", "Can't make the conversion for the same value");
                }
                else if (cur.CurrencyName != cur.CurrencyName)
                {
                    foreach (var currency in cur.CurrencyName)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Theresult = rate * cur.Value;
                    }
                    return PartialView("_CurrencyValue");

                }
            }
            return View();
                }
    }
}
```

Currencies Model

```
namespace Project.Model
{
    public class Currencies
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyCountry {get; set;}
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string ConversionRate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Index View

```
@model Project.Model.Currencies

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }


<h2>Currency</h2>

<body>
    <div class="converter">
        Convert: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConversionRate, new { @size = "5" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Convert from", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Currency List", ViewBag.listCurrencies as SelectList, "Please Select a currency")

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Convert to", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Currency List", ViewBag.listCurrencies as SelectList, "Please Select a currency")
            </div>
        </div>


        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Convert</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's your `form`?  Why do you have a `body` element in a partial view, shouldn't that be in the layout view?  Is this posting to the server at all?  What is the result from the server?  It's not really clear how this is failing.

Comment: That's not indicated in the code shown in the question.  Nor does that really describe a problem.  Though it does show a casing difference between `TheResult` and `Theresult`.  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: I only have <h3>@ViewBag.TheResult</h3> in my PartialView. The above is a view, the view gets the result but no posting is happening and I get a drop down list of CurrencyNames from the server

Comment: I noticed that David and had corrected it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to notice, is the `POST` action and missing `form` tag in the view . You created a POST action that accepts `Currencies` model but the form doesn't post that. Only `ConversionRate` will bind to the model. To get the "Currency From" and "Currency To" and the "Conversion Rate" you will require a different approach/small changes.

ConversionModel.cs a new Model for index page that will capture your required fields.

```
public class ConversionModel
{
    [Required]//decimal would be better but up to you requirement
    public decimal ConversionRate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FromCurrencyId {get;set;}
    public SelectList FromCurrencies {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public int ToCurrencyId {get;set;}
    public SelectList ToCurrencies {get;set;}
}
```

Get: while there is nothing wrong with what you've done, lets use a model approach and tightly bind it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CurrenciesClient Cur = new CurrenciesClient();
    var listCurrency = Cur.findAll();

    ConversionModel model = new ConversionModel();
    model.FromCurrencies = new SelectList(listCurrency,"Id", "CurrencyName");
    model.ToCurrencies = new SelectList(listCurrency,"Id", "CurrencyName");

    return View(model);

}
```

Post: Important thing here to notice is the `SelectList` will not be posted back. Only the `ConversionRate`, `FromCurrencyId` and `ToCurrencyId` are sent back not the Lists. If error occurs you will need to rebuild the lists and send it back in the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ConversionModel curModel)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(curModel.FromCurrencyId ==curModel.ToCurrencyId)
        {
            //do something if same currecnies and return.
        }
        else
        {
            //Get the currencyList with rates  from db
            //use currency ToCurrencyId and FromCurrencyId to fetch the 2 currencies
            // perform conversion with curModel.ConversionRate with existing logic
        } 
    }
    //Don'f forget to rebuild the Select Lists... 
    return View(curModel);
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.Model.ConversionModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Currency", FormMethod.Post)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConversionRate, new { @size = "5" })
    @* Please check the syntax *@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCurrencyId , Model.FromCurrencies as SelectList)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ToCurrencyId , Model.ToCurrencies as SelectList)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Convert</button>
}
```

Not a CUT_COPY_PASTE. please do check for errors if any. It is only an approach.

`ajax` POST probably the next thing to learn... Let us know.

Comment: Searching, thank you very much for your approach. As I mentioned before that I am still a learning and had so many things to look at in MVC and I agree with learning IS NOT COPY/ PASTE! Within the drop down list Model.FromCurrencies is it the model name i.e. Currencies?

Comment: Another question, why not using a ViewBag?

Comment: @Dodi82 The `Model` here is `ConversionModel`  and `Model.FromCurrencies` here is the same `SelectList` that you were previously building, but now just inside the Model. Since we are only interested in the selected currency Id and we use a `SelectList` to build our dropdown, the remaining properties of your `Currencies` model is not required/used. Nothing wrong at all using `ViewBag`.. I personally prefer having a strongly bound object that i can play with. I see `ViewBag` as a temporary save/use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and explanation, I appreciate your time. Using the         @Html.DropDownList(m => m.FromCurrencyId, Model.FromCurrencies as SelectList) throws an exception of Severity "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type", do you know why?

Comment: Sorry it should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCurrencyId, Model.FromCurrencies as SelectList)`

Comment: Just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCurrencyId, Model.FromCurrencies)` - you don't need to cast `SelectList` to `SelectList` :)

Comment: Thanks again! DataBinding: 'ConversionModel ' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'. Does the drop down list conflict with the ID that exists in the cuurency table?

Comment: at what point or when do you get that error? Are you rebuilding the SelectLists `curModel` if the POST fails ?

Comment: The exception at this line: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCurrencyId, Model.FromCurrencies)

Comment: Did you update the view with `@model Project.Model.ConversionModel` ? May be it's still with `@model Project.Model.Currencies` ?

Comment: @model Project.Model.Currencies (copy from the Index View)

Comment: Sorry I did not follow that. What do mean by *copy from the Index View* ? The ` ConversionModel` should be in `Project.Model` namespace . The Index page i added is complete (with no formatting) which should just work.. And the model should be `@model Project.Model.ConversionModel`, we do not use `@model Project.Model.Currencies` here anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130860/discussion-between-dodi82-and-searching).

Comment: Searching, I've got it working on the get Index but I have an error of  The ViewData item that has the key is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable' when I try to post!

Comment: @Dodi82 it seems that the model is binding to wrong property. Check the view and see if there are any properties with same name. Would be better if you could create a question with the code view and the error. It's just easier to see what's been done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your items inside a form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Currency", FormMethod.Post)
{
    // Your form items
}
```

Comment: I altered my code as recommended in your answer. When I press the convert button I get: The  HTTP 404 exception!

Comment: see my edit. I am not sure if you changed the action name to your action name and the controller. I have edited my code and I have changed the action name and the controller name. If you still get the 404, let me know the details of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have solved the issue but part of it is still working as it should. Searching tried to help but we could not come up with a solution. The problem was an exception on the GET action method as keep getting a null value on the var listCurrency = Cur.findAll().ToList(); line? If you can help, it would be appreciated!